# Pyqt Terminal hangs after excuting close window command

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have read lots of threads online, but still I could not find the solution. My question should be very simple: how to close a Pyqt window WITHOUT clicking a button or using a timer.
The code I tried is pasted below

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import progressMeter_simple
import sys
import time
import pdb
class ProgressMeter(progressMeter_simple.Ui_Dialog, QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        progressMeter_simple.Ui_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 0)
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
    def termination(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        self.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = ProgressMeter()
    Dialog.show()
    Dialog.termination()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My Pyqt GUI is designed using Qt designer, and it is nothing but a progress bar that keeps moving from left to right (busy indication).

However, when I run the code above, the terminal still hangs after the Pyqt window is closed. Ctrl+C also couldn't kill the process. 
In short, how can I properly close/terminate a Pyqt window without clicking a button or using a timer?

Comment: Hook the close signal on Progress up to `app.exit`.

Comment: Well, the solution **is** very simple if you use a `QTimer`. What make you think you can't use one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you're calling GUI methods on the dialog (`close()`) outside of the event loop.  The event loop doesn't start until you call `app.exec_()`.

If you really want to close the dialog *immediately* after it opens without using a `QTimer`, you can override the [`showEvent()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#showEvent) method and call `termination()` from there, which gets called when the dialog is first displayed.

```
class ProgressMeter(progressMeter_simple.Ui_Dialog, QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        progressMeter_simple.Ui_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 0)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(ProgressMeter, self).showEvent(event)
        self.termination()
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now it makes much more sense. There is a way to close the whole thing outside of the event loop then? This is actually what I am trying to do.

Comment: No, the `showEvent` doesn't get called until *after* the event loop starts.  To stop the event loop, it has to be something that is called from within the event loop.